# Why does timeit take so long with pandas methods and how to time it?

Tags: pandas, timeit

I want to time a pandas method to compare with native python but it just hangs.

`timeit("df.iloc[-1]", setup='import pandas as pd; df = pd.DataFrame([[1,1]])')`

Why is this? And it there a way to use timeit with pandas?

Update:
I also tried moving the setup outside the timit function as follows but it still takes a long time (38s)

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,1]])
timeit("df.iloc[-1]", globals=locals())
```

Comment: What do you mean? It works for me in 26 seconds.

Comment: I guess I didn't wait long enough....but why is it so long? pandas is very fast when not using timeit

Comment: I think the problem is the `setup` because `%timeit df.iloc[-1]` is extremely fast.

Comment: I've editing my question to show that moving the setup to before the timeit call still makes it take a long time, so I think it's the `df.iloc[-1]` which is taking long